# How to obtain the remainder in a Python binary conversion program?

Tags: python

I am trying to create a decimal to binary converter for a university project
(so please no answers, just guidance). I cannot use any inbuilt features, and I also must have a loop.

Does anybody have an idea on how I can get the remainder to save somewhere for a final print in reverse order to obtain the binary number?

Here is my code:

```
quotient = int(input("Enter a number: "))
count=0

#find remainder
#divide quotient by 2
#loop until quotient is 0
while quotient != 0:
    remainder = quotient%2
    quotient = quotient//2   
    print(remainder)

    count +=1
    result[count] = remainder
```

Comment: _No answers?_ This site is all about questions and _answers_!

Comment: Could you explicitly list the problems you have with the current version of your code?

Comment: Don't use a dict, use a list...

Comment: im facepalming myself because i just cannot grasp this! I'm now trying to work out how I would add the binary digit into the list in order to reverse and print? any code written i will have to rewrite anyway so technically not cheating (Y)

Answer (score 0):

`result` should be a list instead of a dict. Then you can just call `reversed` on it to get what you want and join it with an empty string.

```
>>> def bin_conv(n):
...   result = []
...   quotient = n
...   while quotient != 0:
...     remainder = quotient % 2
...     quotient //= 2
...     result.append(remainder)
...   return result
...
>>> bin_conv(0)
[]
>>> bin_conv(1)
[1]
>>> bin_conv(2)
[0, 1]
>>> bin_conv(3)
[1, 1]
>>> bin_conv(4)
[0, 0, 1]
>>> bin_conv(5)
[1, 0, 1]
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the `while` loop you already have, you need two things:

1. `x & 1` will give you the last binary digit of `x`.
2. `x >>= 1` will shift the last digit out.

Together this will give you all digits in reverse order. It will be your turn to store, reverse and output the result.

Comment: so if i input: quotient & 1, will that output the remainder?

Comment: Open the Python interpreter, enter the expression, see the result! ;-)

Comment: Ah I see! How would I place that result into a list incrementally and at the end print the list in reverse without using the (reversed) function?

Comment: `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5][::-1]` → `[5, 4, 3, 2, 1]`

Comment: And every list has an `append()` method.

Comment: is there any way to add each remainder to the list in a separate spot so it turns out as [0,0,1,1,1,1,0,1][::-1] etc.? for example (add first remainder to list[count] and increment count+=1 at the end of the loop)?

Comment: I am not allowed to use append for some reason.

Comment: `[1,2,3,4,5] + [6]` will do the same. Hint: That also works the other way around.

Comment: im facepalming myself because i just cannot grasp this! I'm now trying to work out how I would add the binary digit into the list in order to reverse and print? any code written i will have to rewrite anyway so technically not cheating (Y)

Answer (score 0):

You can save the remainders to a list named 'result'. Append new remainders to the list in every iterations as they come along.

Now the elements of the list are in reverse order as they should be to qualify as the binary equivalent. So we have to print the list elements in the backward order using negative indexing.

Also we want the result to be printed in one line without any space in between. This is achieved by using `end=''` within the print function.

```
quotient = int(input("Enter a number: "))
count=0
result=[]
while quotient != 0:
    remainder = quotient%2
    quotient = quotient//2   
    count +=1
    result.append(remainder)
n=1
while n<=len(result):
    print (result[-n],end='')
    n=n+1
print('\n')
```